# Magic launcher/minecraft problem Logging in?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

When I try to login to Magic Launcher to play Minecraft it Says logging in for about 30 seconds and then it says "Error Connecting to server" so I clicked Details and got:

```
MagicLauncher 1.0.0
java.home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
java.runtime.name: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version: 1.7.0_09-b05
os.name: Windows Vista
os.version: 6.0
os.arch: x86
sun.arch.data.model: 32
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: https://login.minecraft.net/
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at magic.launcher.ak.a(Unknown Source)
    at magic.launcher.z.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

that means the login server is down

check http://help.mojang.com/ for the up to date status of all servers

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and all I did was extract the .zip file from the folder you downloaded and use that instead. It works for me. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

A 504 response means that the servers are not up and running. You can try again soon. Also, visiting http://help.mojang.com/ would be beneficial. They have a nice little bit of JavaScript that alerts you of the statuses of all Minecraft services.